# Detecting hanging processes in Perl/MySQL (FreeBSD)

Tags: mysql, perl, apache, freebsd, dbi

I have a Perl script running on a FreeBSD/Apache system, which makes some simple queries to a MySQL database via DBI.  The server is fairly active (150k pages a day) and every once in a while (as much as once a minute) something is causing a process to hang.  I've suspected a file lock might be holding up a read, or maybe it's a SQL call, but I have not been able to figure out how to get information on the hanging process.

Per Practical mod_perl it sounds like the way to identify the operation giving me the headache is either system trace, perl trace, or the interactive debugger.  I gather the system trace is ktrace on FreeBSD, but when i attach to one of the hanging processes in top, the only output after the process is killed is:

```
50904 perl5.8.9 PSIG  SIGTERM SIG_DFL
```

That isn't very helpful to me.  Can anyone suggest a more meaningful approach on this?  I am not terribly advanced in Unix admin, so your patience if I sound stupid is greatly appreciated....  :o)

Comment: I would try and add some signal handling and logging to start. It would definitely help to have mysql logging enabled as well if you can in order to see what was being done before/during the lock timestamp - this might give some further insight. Do you happen to be using threads? Any log information you could post would probably help any potential SO users in helping you as well.
For signal handling there's always the posix module - http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#POSIX%3a%3aSigAction

Comment: The best situation would be if someone can recognize the error, but otherwise you have to start logging your way out of it. I postprocessed my logs so they are distilled to one line per request, only containing a description of major state changes with a required start- and end state. You should then be able to find lines that don't have the required end state and use the last logged state as a hint in which direction you should do more logging.

Answer (score 0):

Ktracing only gives you system calls, signals I/O and namei processing. And it generates a *lot* of data very quickly. So it might not be ideal to fish out trouble spots.

If you can see the standard output for your script, put some strategically placed print statements in your code around suspected trouble spots. Then running the program should show you were the hang occurs:

```
print "Before query X"
$dbh->do($statement)
print "After query X".
```

If you cannot see the standard output, either use e.g. the [Sys::Syslog](http://search.cpan.org/~saper/Sys-Syslog-0.32/Syslog.pm) perl module, or call FreeBSD's `logger(1)` program to write the debugging info to a logfile. It is probably easiest to encapsulate that into a `debug()` function and use that instead or print statements.

**Edit:** If you don't want a lot of logging on disk, write the logging info to a socket (Sys::Syslog supports that with `setlogsock()`), and write another script to read from that socket and dump the debug text to a terminal, prefixed with the time the data was received. Once the program hangs, you can see what it was doing.

Comment: Great answer.  The problem is the script runs a million times before it locks up once, so that would be an immense amount of data logging, and i suppose would put some load on the server.  Given the limitation that the lock-up is extremely rare, how might you suggest I track the lock-up without excessive server load and a lot of false positives?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your Perl process is hanging while querying the MySQL, which, by itself, is still operational. MySQL server has the embedded troubleshooting feature for that, the [log_slow_queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-queries) option. Putting the following lines in your `my.cnf` enables the trick:

```
[mysqld]
log_slow_queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 10
```

After that, restart or reload the MySQL daemon. Let the server run for a while to collect the stats and analyse what's going on:

```
mysqldumpslow -s at /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log | less
```

On one server of mine, the top record (`-s at` orders by average query time, BTW) is:

```
Count: 286  Time=101.26s (28960s)  Lock=14.74s (4214s)  Rows=0.0 (0), iwatcher[iwatcher]@localhost
  INSERT INTO `wp_posts` (`post_author`,`post_date`,`post_date_gmt`,`post_content`,`post_content_filtered`,`post_title`,`post_excerpt`,`post_status`,`post_type`,`comment_status`,`ping_status`,`post_password`,`post_name`,`to_ping`,`pinged`,`post_modified`,`post_modified_gmt`,`post_parent`,`menu_order`,`guid`) VALUES ('S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S','S')
```

FWIW, it is a WordPress with over 30K posts.

Comment: I don't think it's MySQL, since the lock-ups occurred without that part of the script.  I ended up moving the server to a Ubuntu/Nginx box, which uses fastcgi.  I had to do some rewriting of the skin script, but the rare lock-up still seems to occur.  I have a cron script which checks for a locked up process, and just restarts the FCGI wrapper, which is a very poor solution, but does keep the box running.99.99% of the time.  I tried going over the script line by line but nothing jumped out.  My colleague suggested I move the whole thing to PHP, which is easier said than done.

Comment: FCGI wrapper is known to be hard to tune; I've experienced many sudden locks with it, indeed. On the other side, Nginx plays really nice with PSGI. You could try to wrap your CGI with PSGI, using https://metacpan.org/module/CGI::Emulate::PSGI, for instance.

Comment: Note that there might be better or worse ways of doing that; you can even plug the good old `cgi-bin` back to the Nginx: https://metacpan.org/module/Plack::App::CGIBin (probably it will be slow as hell, but won't be able to hog resources enough to hang the server).